# Showing Html formatted string in Webbrowser with black background flicks

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, meta

I am developing a windows phone 8 application. In my application i am using a WebBrowser control to show the HTML formatted string. I need to show the html formatted text with black background. I am doing it successfully but the **Problem is that**

when the html formatted string is rendered in WebBrowser it first shows the White color and then shows the actual string with black background. It looks like **flick** effect and then shows my html formatted string.

**Code I am Using is:**

```
string html = ("<!DOCTYPE html5><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"user-scalable=no background-color:black\" />" + sctipy + "</head><body style= \"background:#000; color:#fff;\"><div id=\"content\">" + myHtmlFormattedString + "</div></body>" + "</html>");
webbrowser.NavigateToString(html);
```

Is there any other solution like changing the default background of WebBrowser control to other than white

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't change the background of the WebBrowserControl itself.

I had the same problem... I solved it by making the WebBrowserControl collapsed and when the `LoadCompleted` of the WebBrowserControl hits, make it visible...

XAML:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Visibility="Collapsed" LoadCompleted="WebBrowser_LoadCompleted" />
```

And on the back:

```
public void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e);
{
   browser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

This gives you also the advantage to show a ProgressBar/ProgressRing when you are loading a (huge) page and hide until the `WebBrowser_LoadCompleted` gets triggered. As you are loading a small page, you won't see the difference of the visible/collapsed part and your flickering problem is gone...